# swift custom uitextviewcell label always nil

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, null

i'm stuck here since two days ago, and cant find how to manage this..
I have an uitableview, with an array of custom cells and sections, here's what i want to do:

- Section 1: just a row with a label inside
- Section 2: a datepicker (i used DVDatePickerTableViewCell class for this)

here's the code for the table view

```
import UIKit

class DettagliRichiestaTVC: UITableViewController {
    //sections contiene le sezioni
    let sections: NSArray = ["Stato", "Data", "Priorità", "Richiesta", "Risposta"]
    //cells contiene tutte le righe della tabella, un 2D array
    var cells:NSArray = []
    var stato:String = "Completato"
    @IBOutlet weak var statoLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       // statoLabel.text = stato

        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44

        // Cells is a 2D array containing sections and rows.
        var cellStato = cellDettagli(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cellStato")
        cellStato.label?.text = "Ciao"
        cells = [
            [cellStato],
            [DVDatePickerTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: nil)]
        ]

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func selectedStato(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
        let statoRichiesteTVC = segue.sourceViewController as StatoRichiesteTVC
        if let selectedStato = statoRichiesteTVC.selectedStato {
            statoLabel.text = selectedStato
            stato = selectedStato
        }
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        var headerFrame:CGRect = tableView.frame


        var title = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 20))
        title.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(12.0)
        title.text = self.sections.objectAtIndex(section) as? String
        title.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.6, green: 0.6, blue: 0.6, alpha: 1)

        var headerView:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, headerFrame.size.width, headerFrame.size.height))
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.8)
        headerView.addSubview(title)

        return headerView
    }



    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        var cell = self.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
        if (cell.isKindOfClass(DVDatePickerTableViewCell)) {
            return (cell as DVDatePickerTableViewCell).datePickerHeight()
        }
        return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    }


    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return cells.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cells[section].count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return cells[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] as UITableViewCell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        var cell = self.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
        if (cell.isKindOfClass(DVDatePickerTableViewCell)) {
            var datePickerTableViewCell = cell as DVDatePickerTableViewCell
            datePickerTableViewCell.selectedInTableView(tableView)
        }
        self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        //println(segue.identifier)
        if segue.identifier == "SavePlayerDetail" {
        }
        if segue.identifier == "SelezionaStatoRichiesta" {
            let statoRichiesteTVC = segue.destinationViewController as StatoRichiesteTVC
            statoRichiesteTVC.selectedStato = stato
        }
    }

}
```

and here's the custom cell class

```
import UIKit

class cellDettagli: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    func loadItem(#Label: String) {
        label.text = Label
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        //fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }


    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

if i set cellStato.label?.text = "Ciao" , it crashes saying "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" .

I created also the .xib file and assigned that to cellDettagli class.
I always get that error.

How can i set the values of this label, and the date of the datepicker row?

Thank you

Comment: Why are you creating an array of cells?

Comment: the table is made of custom cells that may change during the use of the app. Plus, i may need to create different similar tables in other storyboards, the same way..

Comment: Yes. But neither of those are reasons for creating an array of stored cells. You should always dequeue the cells using the tablviews dequeue method. Which is actually what you're doing in your answer. Btw your answer basically ignores the cells array that I was questioning in the first place.

Comment: Yes i understand and in my 2nd answer i'm doing this without array.. but.. in this way i need to know every cell before loading.. what can i do if i dont know these, but only know their classes/value, and not the order or presence of these cells?

Comment: That sounds like you're storing data in the cells. You shouldn't be doing that at all. The only thing that should matter in terms of order is the data. The cells are not in any order. In fact the cells should be reused and so will always be shifting around.

Comment: Uhm maybe i'm doing everything wrong.. i try to explain what i need, if you can please help: I have a php db online, and i want to add/edit it's data from some tables inside my app. Since all tables in db look similar, i'd like to describe in each storyboard something like: Table:"tb_name", Id: 1, Columns: {Name:"Column1",Type:"text",Value:"hello this is the value},{Name:"StartDate",Type:"date",Value:"2015-02-12"} , and the table populate itself from this. i've no problem with the connecting part to the php server, or authentication, but i can't think about where to start for this.. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

I made it work using this:

```
var cell:cellDettagli? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellDettagli") as? cellDettagli
if  (cell==nil){
   var nib:NSArray=NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("cellDettagli", owner: self, options: nil)
   cell = nib.objectAtIndex(0) as? cellDettagli
}
```

inside my cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Thank you Alexander for your help! I already use static cells and storyboards...!

Answer (score 1):

You're creating cells using the designated initialiser, which means the views that you've added in the nib won't be there at runtime. You will need to register your nib with the tableview first using `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:`, then dequeue cells accordingly using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html

Since it looks like you're using static cells, you might be better off using a storyboard with "Static Cells" content type on your table view instead of "Dynamic Prototypes".

For more information on static cells, see the docs https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html

Comment: The Q says XIB, but a similar answer applies as the NIB needs t be loaded

Comment: Sorry, but i cant understand the meaning of your answer (i'm a newbie programmer, sorry)

so, i add this 

self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "cellDettagli", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellStato")

into viewDidLoad, before creating my var cellStato in my UITableViewController class..

but then, where and how to dequeue that cell?
Sorry, and thanks for your answer!

Comment: Also, is there a better method to achieve what i need?

Comment: In answer to your first comment, you will dequeue the cell inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. In answer to your second comment, yes, using static cells in a storyboard is suited to your needs. However, if you're not using storyboards in your project already then that may too big a change to implement.